# Epub: Paragraph breaks in unwanted places and leaves Widows

Tags: epub, calibre, indesign, google-play-books, kindlegen

I converted my book from print format (indesign) to .mobi by exporting it via a kindle export plugin. After that I used Calibre to convert it to an epub. When I view the book on Google play Books reader, I see that in some places my paragraphs are breaking in odd places when the page ends and the last line consists of one or two words (widows) hanging in there abruptly. Sometimes the reader displays an entire page as between two paragraphs although there is no HTML that relates to it.

I checked the in-design document and found no page breaks or other break characters. I also checked the HTML code for any 
 tags that may have come up but I found nothing.

I have tried to to do some research and use standard techniques for e pub creation also but to no avail. The breaks still occur.

This issue occurs with almost all of my books and I have tried to replace the fonts too.

Kindly help to resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many epub apps don't render ebooks in Indic languages correctly. However, there's one more thing that you could try.

Open your epub with Sigil or Calibre Editor and add the following parameters to the paragraph section of the main stylesheet:

```
p {
   /* more entries */
   /* more entries */
    orphans: 2;
    widows: 2;
}
```

This should theoretically fix your issue, however, many epub apps don't support the widows and orphans parameters.

Obviously, this solution only works with DRM-free ebooks.